# Regex phone number live formatting

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

In AngularJS, I need to format phone numbers while they are being typed.
I don't want to use any library as this should be straight forward.

The format I need is : `99 99 99 99 99`

```
var phone = tel.replace(/\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
```

But this only formats my number once it has been fully typed. How can I make this regular expression work when the number is not yet complete ?

I then tried this :

```
var phone = tel.replace(/\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{0,2})?\D*(\d{0,2})?\D*(\d{0,2})?\D*(\d{0,2})?\D*/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');
```

But this is obviously adding non required spaces.

Comment: Well this is strictly a regex question. the expression is matching once all groups have been recognized. The Angular part is ok.

Comment: Just run the regexp on every change. Use the onchange- or keyup-listener for this.

Comment: You could save some head-ache, and remove "non required spaces" in a second step, wrap the thing in a filter.

Comment: Good point @AJcodez. I'll go ahead with this idea. Thanks.

Comment: @mercredo this is not my issue. I am doing this in a $watch so it is fired properly.

Comment: It doesn't matter its adding trailing spaces. They are not visible are they? Just do a cascading style match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you want it to be "straight forward", yet you're artificially constraining the problem (by forcing the solution to be only regex) when pure regex is actually a poor solution to this problem.

Why? Because your problem involves conditionally adding new characters to the output (the spaces) that may not appear in the input, but shouldn't always be added - `.replace()` isn't equipped to deal with that.

You'd be better off using a combination of regex and other JavaScript to handle the conditional formatting:

```
// Get only the digits from the string
var phoneDigits = tel.replace(/\D/g, "");
// Join together the first up-to-5 pairs of digits with spaces,
// allowing for a singleton if the number of digits is odd.
var phone = (phoneDigits.match(/\d\d?/g) || []).slice(0,5).join(" ");
```

(The `|| []` bit avoids the case where the match returns `null` when no digits are present.)

Comment: Oh, nice ! This is great. I just had to add a check for null but other than that it's great.

Comment: @curuba added a tweak to avoid the null case to the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try a cascade style pattern.

`var phone = tel.replace(/\D*(?:(\d{2})\D*(?:(\d{2})\D*(?:(\d{2})\D*(?:(\d{2})\D*(?:(\d{2})\D*)?)?)?)?)?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');`

```
 \D* 
 (?:
      ( \d{2} )                     # (1)
      \D* 

      (?:
           ( \d{2} )                     # (2)
           \D* 

           (?:
                ( \d{2} )                     # (3)
                \D* 

                (?:
                     ( \d{2} )                     # (4)
                     \D* 

                     (?:
                          ( \d{2} )                     # (5)
                          \D* 
                     )?
                )?
           )?
      )?
 )?
```

Comment: This still adds extra spaces, and results in an even more complex regex to boot. Down this path lies madness.

Comment: @Amber - What do spaces have to do with anything?  `"format phone numbers while they are being typed"`  On each keypress, you never see anything other than formatted text. As far as complex regex, madness.. a slight overstatement don't you think ?

Comment: if the formatted value is being placed back into the entry field (which "as it's being typed" often indicates) then extra spaces will result in the cursor jumping around.

Comment: @amber - I guess you could still do a callback replacement using all the capture buffers, then a simple trim call ?